# co-authors plugin - inline listing

Tags: plugins, widgets, author, list-authors, multi-author

I'm trying to set up co-authors plugin in order to show articles authors

```
function inl_users() {
if ( function_exists( 'get_coauthors' ) ) {
  $coauthors = get_coauthors();
  //array_shift($coauthors);
  foreach ( $coauthors as $coauthor ) {
    $autArray[] = '<a href=' . get_author_posts_url( $coauthor->ID ) . '>' . $coauthor->display_name . '</a>';
    echo implode(", ", $autArray);
  }
}
```

The first author is shown twice in the first element, like this:
for `$autArray = (John Smith, Joe Blogs);` it returns `John SmithJohn Smith, Joe Blogs`
full rendered html is like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/author/john-smith/">John Smith</a><a href="https://example.com/author/john-smith/">John Smith</a>, <a href="https://example.com/author/joe-blogs/">Joe Blogs</a>
```

as you can see I've tried to use array_shift() because I thought they were two distinct elements, but they are not
any suggestions?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

solved using for loop instead of foreach:

```
function inl_users() {
if ( function_exists( 'get_coauthors' ) ) {
  $coauthors = get_coauthors();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($coauthors); $i++){
      $autArray[] = '<a href=' . get_author_posts_url( $coauthors[$i]->ID ) . '>' . $coauthors[$i]->display_name . '</a>';
  }
  echo implode(", ", $autArray);
}
```

does anoyone know why?